# How to secure user name/password in JavaScript client interfacing with REST API

Tags: javascript, rest, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a RESTfull web services. This web services will serve as a Web API to the outside world to get some data from our system. So, it will be consumed by other external clients: Mobile Apps, JavaScript clients, etc. For security, it will require Basic HTTP Authentication: user name and password sent as clear text over HTTPS. 
So, I want to put together a proof of concept JavaScript application to demonstrate how one would use this API. But I don't want to hard-code user name/password in JavaScript code, since it can be viewed in page HTML source. In fact I don't want JavaScript to be involved in Authentication at all. So, I was thinking having another web page for server to server authentication. So that client's server sends credential to WEB Appi server, then Web API server issues a token valid for one session only, after that Client server uses this token in JavaScript.
Is this the right approach? If not, what's the "best" solutions for this scenario? I am sure this was done before. Any articles, or code samples will be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: The short answer is don't use basic authentication. There are plenty of solutions on how to do that. See https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/Todo/ReadMe.txt for a sample that shows how to hook Web API to multiple clients.

Comment: As a proof-of-concept, take a look at this article: http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/. It appears to do almost exactly what you want.